# Reading numbers from file and store into 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, filereader

So I'm trying to read and store data into 2d array, from a file that contains this data:
001 012 023 102 113 124 203 214 225
(Where 001 - means row/column/value)
So I can read it, but cannot figure out how to store it into array

```
int [][] arr = new int[3][3];
File file = new File("file.txt");
try(
    FileReader myFile = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(myFile);
){
  System.out.println(buff.readLine());
}catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
  System.out.println("File not found".);
}
```

Comment: What does `System.out.println(buff.readLine());` print?

Comment: it prints my file data :001 012 023 102 113 124 203 214 225

Comment: Okay, now the pattern is always the same. It's row/column/value seperated by spaces. Seems like something where you can use a loop and some methods of [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) to access the values.

Comment: Why do you want store data in 2D array? I mean what is expected structure of data?

Comment: @SatishVarma Well, to use the array after I stored the data into it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after the reading of file, split the values by <kbd>space</kbd> to make an array of values then call the `Character.digit(value.charAt(0), 10)` to change the characters to digit on base of 10 and assign values according to your way:

```
int [][] arr = new int[3][3];
File file = new File("file.txt");

try(
    FileReader myFile = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(myFile);
){
    // String fileData = "001 012 023 102 113 124 203 214 225";
    String fileData = buff.readLine();
    String [] data = fileData.split(" ");
    
    for (String value : data) {
        arr[Character.digit(value.charAt(0), 10)][Character.digit(value.charAt(1), 10)] = Character.digit(value.charAt(2), 10);
    }
    
    for (int[] array : arr) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));         
    }
}catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.println("File not found");
}
```

you can also use `Character.getNumeric` method to convert the character of a digit to an int value:

```
for (String value : data) {
    arr[Character.getNumericValue(value.charAt(0))][Character.getNumericValue(value.charAt(1))] = Character.getNumericValue(value.charAt(2));
}
```

Comment: I was just thinking about charAt() =)

Comment: Yes sir, it solved my problem, thx, and thx also for , 10 - explanation :P